# Get soundcard name/info

Tags: c#, hardware

How can I get the name of the soundcard and maybe a few infos about it when using C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly discontinued but you can still find Managed DirectX which includes ...

```
using Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound;

// List all Audio Cards
DevicesCollection devList = new DevicesCollection();

foreach (DeviceInformation dev in devList)
{
   this.AddToLog("Found {0}, {1}, {2}", dev.Description, dev.DriverGuid, dev.ModuleName);
}
```

Comment: is there no way without directx? maybe via a winapi function call?